# как отключить функцию навигацию в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть Navigation View (drawer) он открывается, когда тянешь пальцем, мне необходимо закрыть это действие , он должен открываться только при нажатии кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17165256/3212712) делается это так:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```